# Вывести строки в Listview используя адаптер

Tags: android, listview, android-layout

Необходимо из строк cm1 и cm2 выводить данные в ListView, каждый раз когда я жму кнопку.
Строки надо выводить, в разных TextView.

**Исходный код:**

Код активити TEST.java:

```
public String cm1;
public String cm2;

public class TEST extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        MyList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listStrings);
        setListAdapter();

        // Кнопка
        Button setup = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
        setup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                cm1 = "cm1text";
                cm2 = "cm2text";
    listItems.add(cm);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }

// Адаптер строки 
    private void setListAdapter() {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.row //дальше хз че писать
    List.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Код TEST.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listStrings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Код row.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cm1tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cm2tv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Как примерно должно выглядеть ListView после 2х нажатий:

```
cm1
cm2
cm1
cm2
```

Comment: ну и что? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте SimpleAdapter

```
MyList = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.listStrings);
private final String ATTRIBUTE_CM1 = "cm1"; 
private final String ATTRIBUTE_CM2 = "cm2";

    // упаковываем данные в понятную для адаптера структуру
    ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
            Map<String, Object> m;

    // массив имен атрибутов, из которых будут читаться данные
    String[] from = {ATTRIBUTE_CM1, ATTRIBUTE_CM2};

    // массив ID View-компонентов, в которые будут вставлять данные
    int[] to = { R.id.cm1tv, R.id.cm2tv };

    // создаем адаптер
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data,
            R.layout.row, from, to);

    MyList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

...

```
 Button setup = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.send);
    setup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            cm1 = "cm1text";
            cm2 = "cm2text";

            // создаем новый Map
            m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_CM1, cm1);
            m.put(ATTRIBUTE_CM2, cm2);
            // добавляем его в коллекцию
            data.add(m);
            // уведомляем, что данные изменились
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
   }
```

Как то так, если я правильно вас понял!